# filter data by first character - Typo3/Extbase plugin

Tags: php, model-view-controller, typo3, extbase

I have to make a typo3 extension which shows streets in a dropdown menu.
Now i need a pagination at the top going from A to Z.

Clicking those links then has to filter out the streets starting with the corresponding character.i tried to make a `listByChar` action in the cities controller  calling 
 `$cities = $this->cityRepository->findByChar();`
 but i have no idea how to pass the character as an argument.. i expected that to be possible by using the uri viewhelper 
(`<f:uri.action controller="***"  action="***"  arguments="{***}" />`).

This is how i show/handle the streets in my show.html:

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option>Straße auswählen</option>
    <f:for each="{city.streets}" as="street">
        <option value="<f:uri.action controller="Street"  action="show"  arguments="{street : street}" />" >{street.name}</option>
    </f:for>
</select>
```

and these are my functions:

*/classes/controller/cityController.php*

```
/**
 * action listByChar
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function listByCharAction() {
    $cities = $this->cityRepository->findByChar();
    $this->view->assign('cities', $cities);

}
```

/classes/domain/repository/CityRepository.php

```
public function findByChar($char){
    *** I yet didn't figure this part out either :C
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you expected correctly, you can pass the char as an argument of the uri.action viewhelper. Since you only need the first character of the streetname use `f:format.crop`.

show.html:

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option>Straße auswählen</option>
    <f:for each="{city.streets}" as="street">
        <option value='<f:uri.action controller="Street"  action="show"  arguments="{char : \"{street.name -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: 1, append: '')}\"}" />' >{street.name}</option>
    </f:for>
</select>
```

In your controller you can get the passed argument with `$this->request->getArgument('char')`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like that the `streets` are related to the `City` and have their own model and repository. So Inject the street repository in your city controller and use the `findByChar` function in your street repository.

/classes/controller/cityController.php:

```
 /**
 * streetRepository
 *
 * @var \VENDOR\ExtensionName\Domain\Repository\StreetRepository
 * @inject
 */
 protected $streetRepository;

 /**
 * action listByChar
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function listByCharAction() {
    $streets = $this->streetRepository->findByChar( $this->request->getArgument('char') );
    $this->view->assign('streets', $streets);
 }
```

/classes/domain/repository/**StreetRepository**.php:

```
public function findByChar($char){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching($query->like('name', $char . '%'));
    return $query->execute();
}
```

Comment: I tried editing this to make it work the eay i need it... but all i managed to archive are links leading me to white pages :( when i pass e.g. 'A' as an argument, cant i send it to the repository directly?

Comment: after enabling error reporting i can see "Call to a member function findByChar() on a non-object" appear

Comment: Have you injected the street repository correctly? Make sure you changed \VENDOR\ExtensionName\ to your vendor and extension name